# Listbox not showing values after DataBind from a comma delimited string

Tags: c#, .net

```
promoIDs = "Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4";
string[] values = promoIDs.Split(',');
lstBoxPromoItems.DataSource = values;
lstBoxPromoItems.DataBind();
```

Its populated (has  but the listbox is not showing the values?

Is it because I haven't set the .DataTextField or .DataValueField?

Listbox is a `System.Web.UI.WebControl.ListBox`

Comment: Try .ToList (); on values.

Comment: You said it's populated; what is it showing, if not the values?

Comment: Nothing, its appearance is\ empty! it has 4 rows as expected but nothing is displayed

Comment: It sounds like it's perhaps setting your values to the Value of each item, but they all have no "text" property assigned to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method is you can add **ListItem** to **ListBox** manually.

```
string promoIDs = "Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4";
string[] values = promoIDs.Split(',');
foreach (string value in values)
{
    string item = value.Trim(); // Trim the spaces
    lstBoxPromoItems.Items.Add(new ListItem(item, item));
}
```

Comment: I should have said its .net 2.0, no var

Comment: That's easy enough to fix. You should know that it's iterating strings then in the array.

Comment: @Stan Thank you for reminding. I updated the answer.